# Sum various columns to get subtotal depending on a criteria from a row using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, sum

I have a csv file, that contains the next data:

> Pages,Pages BN,Pages Color,Customer
> 145,117,28,Report_Alexis
> 46,31,15,Report_Alexis
> 75,27,48,Report_Alexis
> 145,117,28,Report_Jack
> 46,31,15,Report_Jack
> 75,27,48,Report_Jack
> 145,117,28,Report_Amy
> 46,31,15,Report_Amy
> 75,27,48,Report_Amy

So what i need to do , is sum each column  based on the report name and the export to another csv file like this

> Pages,Pages BN,Pages Color,Customer
> 266,175,91,Report_Alexis
> 266,175,91,Report_Jack
> 266,175,91,Report_Amy

How can i do this?

I tried with this:

```
$coutnpages = Import-Csv "C:\temp\testcount\final file2.csv" |where {$_.Filename -eq 'Report_Jack'} | Measure-Object -Property Pages -Sum
```

then

```
$Countpages.Sum | Set-Content -Path "C:\temp\testcount\final file3.csv"
```

But this is just one, and then i dont know how to follow.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working code**

```
$IdentityColumns = @('Customer')
$ColumnsToSum = @('Pages', 'Pages BN', 'Pages Color')
$CSVFileInput = 'S:\SCRIPTS\1.csv'

Import-Csv -Path $CSVFileInput |
    Group-Object -Property $IdentityColumns |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $resultHT = @{ Customer = $_.Name }     # This is result HashTable (Key-Value collection). We add here sum's next line.
        @($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property $ColumnsToSum -Sum ) |    # Run calculating of sum for all $ColumnsToSum`s in one line
            ForEach-Object { $resultHT[$_.Property] = $_.Sum }     # For each calculated property we set property in result HashTable
        return [PSCustomObject]$resultHT     # Convert HashTable to PSCustomObject. This better.
    } |     # End of ForEach-Object by groups
    Select @($ColumnsToSum + $IdentityColumns) |     # This sets order of columns. It may be important.
    Out-GridView     # Or replace with Export-Csv
    #Export-Csv ...
```

**Explanation:**

Use `Group-Object` to make collection of *groups*. *Groups* have 4 properties:

- `Name`   - Name of group, equals to stingified values of property(-ies) you're grouping by
- `Values` - Collection of values of properties you're grouping by (not stringified)
- `Count`  - Count of elements grouped into this group
- `Group`  - Values of elements grouped into this group

For grouping by single string properties (in this case it is ok), you can easily use `Name` of group, otherwise, always use `Values`.

So after `Group-Object`, you iterate not on collection-of-rows of CSV, but on *collection-of-collections-of-rows* grouped by some condition.

`Measure-Object` can process more than one propertiy for single pass (not mixing between values from different properties), we use this actively. This results in array of objects with attribute `Property` equal to passed to `Measure-Object` and value (`Sum` in our case). We move those `Property=Sum` pairs to hashtable.

`[PSCustomObject]` converts hashtable to object. Objects are always better for output.

Comment: You sir are a genius. Working like a charm.